# Show the values in dropdown in reverse order in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
class FineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fine
        fields = ['student', 'fine']

        widgets = {
            'student': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'fine': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
         }
```

I have this Django form. The student field is a foreign key. I want to show the students in reverse order in this form in the template. Help please.

Comment: Share your `Fine` and `Student` model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  you don't need it. You can revert Choices in form without knowledge of model.

Comment: @MaximDanilov: a `ModelChoiceField` has no `.choices`, but a `.queryset`... Using `reversed(..)` or anything similar is also not memory efficient, if for example the form is later validated, since that will require loading *all* elements into memory, whereas the validation can be done with fetching a single object.

Comment: @MaximDanilov: finally often it is better to have consistency, so specifying the `ordering` of a model, will properly order the items in *all* `ModelChoiceFIeld`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - try to see row 551 in django.forms.widgets. Choices for Select-Widget are loaded in memory in list form.

Comment: @MaximDanilov: yes, that is during the *rendering* phase: if you use `FineForm(request.POST)` and then `form.is_valid()` it will validate with the queryset, and hence it will *not* load the queryset, if you do not have to render it. If the form is for example valid, and you wish to store it in the database, fetching all elements in memory is a useless operation...

Comment: @MaximDanilov: you should thus try to avoid invoking rendering logic, if it is not necessary, especially since rendering something is often more expensive (it fetches all sorts of extra models), than validating data... That is especially cumbersome if the number of records is huge: in that case often another widget will be used that for example lazily loads a subset based on a search, and this to *avoid* this load on both memory and database-python bandwidth.

Comment: I agree. The rendering goals should only be achieved on the render.

Answer (score 0):

you can always do anything with choices in form.

Easy, but not the best way:

```
class FineForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ... # your staff

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # after super() widget.choices in Select is a list
        self.fields['students'].widget.choices = self.fields['students'].widget.choices[::-1]
```

I don't like this solution.

You need revert choices only before render, isn't it? That's why you should try other possibilities:

- add order_by in Student._meta
- override order_by in self.fields['students'].queryset
- use own ModelChoiceGenerator for Student.objects
- use FormFieldCallback in FormFactory
- define your own Field.widget.render or form.render
- render field manually in your template
- e.t.c (i don't know your project)